# Ionic based on Angular project not found component factory

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ng-modules

The errror:

> Error: No component factory found for LangPopComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

My `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    //
  ],
  imports: [
    //
    ComponentsModule,
    //
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    //
  ],
  providers: [
    //
  ]
})
```

My `component.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [LangPopComponent], // here too
    entryComponents: [LangPopComponent], // see it's imported here
    imports: [
        TranslateModule,
        IonicModule
    ],
    exports: [LangPopComponent], // I well exported this component...
    providers: [
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

in another `page.ts` (homepage):

```
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public popoverCtrl: PopoverController, public translate: TranslateService, public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  PresentPopover(){
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(LangPopComponent);
    popover.present(); // ERROR HERE
  }
}
```

The error is produced when I want to present the component with the popover library provided by Ionic.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Insert `ComponentsModule` in `home.module.ts`

```
import { ComponentsModule } from '../components/components.module';


    imports: [
        ComponentsModule
      ],
```

Comment: Same error here.
`import { ComponentsModule } from '../../components/components.module';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ ComponentsModule ],
  declarations: [
    LangPopComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LangPopComponent
  ],
  exports: [ LangPopComponent ]
})`

Comment: He does not see it `'../../components/components.module'` Fix the address

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/da805eb2b091ad433ad7681f45e104ec.png
It does. And the error would not be this.
Any other ideas?

Comment: If I add to @NgModule.entrypoints and .declarations in the app.module.ts it's working like a charm. Why it would not be working in another module which are imported in the app.module.ts... :-(